# How to encrypt files on my SD card and still be able to access them on my phone seamlessly?

Tags: encryption, android, disk-encryption, file-encryption, sd-card

I'm looking for a way to encrypt files on my SD card in a way that I could still access them on my phone without huge delays if the file is big (100mb).

Is there such a way to do it? I'm using Android and Windows, though I could get around installing Linux for encryption if necessary (not gonna start using it though).

Notes:

- I expect 3rd party apps to seamlessly access these files on the phone; at least a video player, photo and text viewer and file browser.
- I don't care if it's the whole SD card encrypted or just the files, however I want every single file that I placed myself on the SD card encrypted.
- I do not mind installing any applications on any of my devices to be able to use the SD card.

Comment: I am sure you will find this answer interesting: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155142/22992

Comment: Check https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.eds.android; if rooting the Android deviceis an option, you could mount a new filesystem, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any method of encrypting an SD card's contents that would make that SD card viewable on an out-of-the-box Android and Windows installation.

Android doesn't officially support any encryption method on SD cards, but some manufacturers have built in their own encryption scheme for file-based encryption on SD cards.  Encrypting your SD card contents such a scheme will render it unreadable on Windows, however.  Also, it will probably also be unreadable even on another phone of the same model due to the key being tied to the phone.

Windows supports encryption in NTFS in some circumstances but an Android phone won't be able to read that.

Comment: Ah, I didn't explain it fully then - my apologies! I don't mind installing any applications on any of my devices to be able to use my SD card.